# destructor's unexplained behavior while testing deep/shallow copy in C++

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, copy-constructor

```
class String
{
  private:
    char* ptr;
  public:
  
    String(const String& s1)
    {
       int len = strlen(s1.ptr);
       ptr = new char[len+1];
       strcpy(ptr,s1.ptr);
       
    }
    String(char* c)
    {
      int len = strlen(c);
       ptr = new char[len+1];
       strcpy(ptr,c);
       
    }
    ~String()
    { 
      cout<<"DELETING\n";
      delete[] ptr;
    }
    void display()
    {cout<<ptr;}
};

int main()
{
String s("Waqar"); String* s2  =&s;
String s1(s);
delete s2;
s1.display();
```

It goes fine till the second last line `delete s2`. While debugging, it throws an error to the effect of an unknown signal and never executes `s1.display()`.
Being a noob, I was testing deep vs shallow copy concepts in c++ and thus written this junk.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You can only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: ptr was a 'new'. or pointing to dynamically created memory, so to say.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed But `s2` was not.

Comment: so why does it call destructor if not created out of new?

Comment: The only uses of `new` were with type `char[]`, so you can't use `delete` with type `String`. Your program has undefined behavior, and anything could have happened.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed -- If you're going to use output to determine what is being destroyed, you should be printing the value of `this` and `ptr` in the destructor, not just a simple message.  That way, you can see the object that is being destroyed.  Similarly, you should output `this` when constructing the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s2` points to `s`. It is a pointer, and not a copy at all (shallow or otherwise). It was never allocated any memory by `new`. So when you try to delete `s2`, you are asking the program to free up memory on the stack that is not managed by new/delete. Do not `delete s2` in this instance. It is an error. Your destructor is not at fault here.

Here's a sample program detailing how and when the destructor is
called a different points, and only `delete`'s memory that was allocated with `new`.

```cpp
// declare `copy`, but do not initialise it just yet. We want to
// initialise it from `s` (which is not yet declared)
String* copy;
{
    // declare and initialise `s`, and copy "Wagner" into s.ptr
    String s("Wagner");
    // create a new String on the heap, initialised from `s`
    // this is a deep copy because of how you wrote String(String&)
    copy = new String(s);
    s.display();
    // `s` falls out of scope at the end of this block
    // this means that s.~String() is invoked
}
// `copy` is unaffected as it was declared in the outer scope, 
// and because it is a deep copy. Had it been a shallow copy
// then it would be broken as its `char* ptr` would not be valid
// any more.
copy->display();
// copy->~String() is invoked when copy is deleted
delete copy;
```

Comment: Gratitude for the explanation. But what is this feature of c++ enclosed between brackets. I haven't seen this before. Tis whole part. also the first line `String* copy;` It doesn't look like a function or a class syntax

Comment: @WaqarAhmed The braces are used to define a local scope of execution.  It has existed in C++ since the beginning, and is not a new feature.  It even exists in C.

Comment: `String* copy;` is a declaration. It means I you can separate out declaration from initialisation. I did this so that `copy` has a larger scope than `s`. But I cannot initialise `copy` immediately, because it is to be initialised from `s`. `{}` is a "compound statement" or "block", it just bunches together a set of statements (like in loops and functions). Any objects declared in a block fall out of scope at the end of the block, and have their destructors called.